# At which step UX writers must get involved to write UX copy for any product?

Tags: ux-field, ux-writing

I am a UX writer and at times it gets difficult to write a UX copy in the UI design phase. I wanted to understand at which step we can be involved so that us and other tems don't face any difficulty.

Comment: "UX copy", depends how detailed it is. As the process design develops from broad to specific, any copy, instructions, labels that support the process ought to match the same level of detail, from outlines, generalizations...through each step of testing and refinement, to final, detailed product ready for release.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for the points.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I believe UX writers need to get involved as early as possible.

- they might need to do they own research too. e.g. what terms the target users are already familiar with
- Might be able to propose a solution that could simplify the design drastically.
- if they propose the copy earlier, you will be able to use it directly than having to write your own temp copy and update it later.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the same that the sooner we are onboarded the better it is for us also to conduct independent research